# Django rest framework - Raising exception / Handling empty results while filtering

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have a user profile class and am checking if a user exists and if not want to create that user.

Am using the filter class for userprofile so that the client can call :

http://localhost:8000/users/?email=a@b.com

and if the result is empty will create a user with the email address.

Is there a way to intercept the query result and raise an exception when its empty and handle that to create the user.
If there is a better way would like to be corrected as well.

```
class UserQueryFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.FilterSet):
    email = django_filters.CharFilter(name="user__email")
    username = django_filters.CharFilter(name="user__username")

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ['email', 'username']


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_class = UserQueryFilter
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Anand

Answer (score 0):

Django Rest Framework provide a functionality that is disabled by default. Maybe it could give you another approach to resolve your problem: [PUT as create](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#put-as-create)

In other hand, if you really need to create the user through a GET request with a querystring, you can use a `MethodFilter` from django-filters, for example:

```
class UserFilters(FilterSet):
    user = MethodFilter(action='filter_user')

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['user']

    def filter_user(self, queryset, value):
        if not value:
            # Here Raise Exception
        else:
            # Check if the user exists, if not create it
            users = queryset.filter(Q(username=value) | Q(email=value))
            if not users.exists:
                user = User.objects.create(...)
                return queryset.filter(pk=user.id)
            else:
                return users
```

Hope this can help you. I'm not pretty sure about it works in that exact way but it's the idea.

Personally, I recommend you that try to execute that tasks through a more appropriate request like POST or PUT and manage in the corresponding method.